# loop through a mpl::map

Tags: c++, boost, boost-mpl

what is the simple way to loop through a mpl::map?

```
typedef mpl::string<'Curr'> key1;
typedef mpl::string<'Brid'> key2;
typedef mpl::map<pair<key1,int>, pair<key2,char> > m;
```

How can I loop through m ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you use  [`mpl::for_each`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/for-each.html) ? Something like:

```
mpl::for_each<
  m, 
  typename mpl::lambda< 
    mpl::key_type<
      m, 
      mpl::_1
    > 
  > 
>( do_some() );
```